# Downloading files from GSE datasets

Tags: r, bioinformatics, pubmed

Does someone know where I can find the full files (**Matrix, Barcodes and Features**) in GEO datasets? I've been trying to download that from previous studies for a long time ago in order to reproduce the results, but I cannot find them. For example, in some GSE, it is possible to find the 3 files, but in others, it is not! May I missing something? I mean, ought I proceed in a different manner?
Thank you so much!

Below there are 2 clear examples for what I'm referring to:

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSE158380

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSE108788

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Not every submitter deposits the processed data. Even when they do, they are free to attach it to the series (GSE) or the sample (GSM). In the second example, the UMI counts are on GSM as a CSV, rather than the typical CellRanger output: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSM2913270.